# How can I use the return of .DayOfWeek to check property of class

Tags: c#, datetime, dayofweek

I have a scheduler program which allows the user to choose which days of the week it will be allowed to run a schedule.

The properties in my class include each day of the week.

Instead of using 7 statments like `if (Schedule[i].Sunday == true)`

How would I go about something like this:

```
if (Schedule[i].(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek) == true)
```

Comment: Make an `IsAllowed(DayOfWeek)` method?

Comment: It's a ltitle confusing what you're trying to do, can you clarify

Answer (score 1):

You can make `int DaysOfWeek` property in the class, which will have its bits set according to day of week. Let's say `0000001` - Sunday, `0000010` - Monday, `0000011` - Sunday & Monday. I start from Sunday, because DayOfWeek enum starts from Sunday (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/dayofweek.cs).
Then you can check the property the following way:

```
if ((DaysOfWeek & (1 << (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)) != 0)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a multidimensional array for Schedule; your first index will be `i`, and your second one is the day of the week as an integer.

Then cast the `DayOfWeek` to an integer:

```
if (Schedule[i][((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)] == true)
```

Note that I'm using the `DayOfWeek` as the second index, rather than a property. This is why I mentioned using a multidimensional array earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Make an enum with all day of the week set as flags,

```
[Flags]
Enum DaysOfWeek
{
None = 0,
Monday = 1 << 1,
Tuesday 1 << 2,
...
}
```

Then you will be able to use `days.HasFlag(DaysOfWeek.Monday);` to check for specific days.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can also use them in a switch statement to do different actions for each days.

Sadly the current C# `system.dayofweek` has values from 0 to 6 [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so it doesn't work with `HasFlag`

Comment: It's good that System.DayOfWeek has values from 0 to 6 for other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to say without knowing the structure of your Schedule, but if you're storing a `DayOfWeek` type in your Schedule you can use this:

```
Schedule[i].DayOfWeek == DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
```

You could also get a list of scheduled items from your List like this

```
var scheduledItems = schedule.Where(x=>x.DayOfWeek == DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek)
```